# jquery from outside of main form submits form

Tags: jquery, html

i have a standard html based post form that submits data to a php- i have a dropdown that i want a user to add items to when using this form so i have setup a lightbox (using fancybox) to submit a jquery post to the server. the problem is- even tho the div i used is outside the main  and closing  tags the "add album" form still submits the main form?

here is my code

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
            <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
        <p>
            <label for="album_title">Album title</label>
            <input type="text" id="album_title" name="album_title" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="album_description">Album Description</label>
            <input type="text" id="album_description" name="album_description" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <em>Leave empty so see resizing</em>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

    <?=form_open_multipart('socialmedia/add_picstation');?>
    <div class="error"><? echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
        <table width="500" align="left" >
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    If no image is provided through the station- the default image uploaded below will be used
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="table_left"><?=form_label('Status', 'title');?></td>
                <td class="table_right"><?=form_input(array('name'=>'title', 'id'=>'title','style' => 'width:80%'));?></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td class="table_left"><?=form_label('Album', 'album_id',array('id'=>'select_albums'));?></td>
                <td><?=form_dropdown('album_id',$users_albums)?> <a class="iframe" href="<?=base_url()?>/socialmedia/add_album/">This goes to iframe</a>
                <a id="tip5" title="Login" href="#login_form">Try now</a>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="table_right">
                    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt2">WEB CAM PIC</label></div>
                    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1">UPLOAD PIC</label></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;padding-right:70px"><?=form_submit('g','Add');?>
                <?=form_close();?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and my js to handle the form

```
    $("#tip5").fancybox({
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'onStart' :function() {
            $("#login_error").hide();
        },
        'onClosed'      : function() {
            $("#login_error").hide();
        }
    });



    $("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {



        if ($("#album_title").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
            $("#login_error").show();
            $.fancybox.resize();
            return false;
        }

        $.fancybox.showActivity();

        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            cache   : false,
            url     : '<?=base_url()?>/socialmedia/add_album/',
            data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

the problem seems to be that the main form gets submitted by the div's submit button

**update**

i pretty much copied the example at http://fancybox.net/blog (tip5) to a t as it pretty much done what i wanted- the issue is just the login form submits the wrong form even though the div appears outside of the form tags of the main form

Comment: I'll tell you right off the bat - you can't open a `form` in a table cell and close it in a different cell. `form`s are just like any other HTML tag. They need to fully contain all elements inside them and need to be fully contained by another element.

Comment: i had it like that - thought this may make a difference- should have updated the code before i posted it here

Comment: So, to clarify, you're saying that the `login_form`/`add_album` form is being submitted when you click the submit button in the `add_picstation` form? Could you post the HTML output of your PHP (like View Source in your browser)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit to a separate action URL, you need to prevent the main form from sending:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Call your AJAX here
});
```